# Is there a way to access class nested in generic class without specifying type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following set of classes:

```
public abstract class User<T> where T : Permission
{
    public ICollection<T> Permissions { get; set; }

    public class Client : User<Permission.Client> { }

    public class Admin : User<Permission.Admin> { }
}

public abstract class Permission
{
    public class Client : Permission { }

    public class Admin : Permission { }
}
```

You're able to create an instance of `User<T>.Client` while passing a type parameter to `User<T>` other than what the class itself uses in implementing `User<T>`. In the following example, `User<T>.Client` is being created with `T` as `Permission.Admin`, even though the class actually implements `User<T>` with `Permission.Client`:

```
var client = new User<Permission.Admin>.Client();
client.Permissions.Add(new Permission.Client());
client.Permissions.Add(new Permission.Admin()); // cannot convert from 'Permission.Admin' to 'Permission.Client'
```

There is at least the build error that prevents adding an `Admin` permission to the `Client` user. However, the usage can be misleading since the type parameter being passed to `User<T>` seems to be superfluous.

---

**Question**: Is there a way to create an instance of a `User<T>.Client` without having to specify type parameter `T` on `User` (e.g. `User.Client`)?

Here's a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9pzPM8) with the full example.

Comment: No. Since `Permission` is generic, `Permission<int>.Client` and `Permission<string>.Client` are different types. If you want to be able to say `new Permission.Client()`, but it in a new class/namespace called `Permission`

Comment: Move Client out of your User<T> class and you can create an instance with `new Client()`? or make Client nested class of non generic User class?

Comment: It `seems to be superfluous` because of the nesting. @ChristophLütjen is correct, just move the `Client` class outside of the other one and it will no longer be misleading.

Comment: Follow the comments above, having a non generic class and inside generic class then expecting usage W/o type parameter is correct. Here still reflection may help, but not recommended in general, since the design is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what everyone has said in the comments, about the nested classes, if you want your user permissions to container both client and admin permissions, you need to be using a collection of type Permission

```
public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; } = new List<Permission>();
```

That'll fix your example, but not make your code any easier to follow.

Update:
Is there a reason why your code couldn't be more like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new ClientUser();
        client.Permissions.Add(new ClientPermission());
        //This should fail because a client user can't have admin permissions
        client.Permissions.Add(new AdminPermission()); // cannot convert from 'AdminPermission' to 'ClientPermission'
    }


    public abstract class User<T> where T : Permission
    {
        public ICollection<T> Permissions { get; set; } = new List<T>();
    }

    public class ClientUser : User<ClientPermission> { }

    public class AdminUser : User<AdminPermission> { }

    public abstract class Permission
    {
    }

    public class ClientPermission : Permission { }

    public class AdminPermission : Permission { }
}
```